Reducing root partition in VPS (Ubuntu 20.04)
I have a virtual server that does not have access to rescue mode I only have ssh access
My disk size is 100 GB, which is all allocated to the root partition when installing the operating system.
I need to reduce the size of the root partition to 20GB and create a new partition with the remaining 80GB.
Is there a solution for this?

Restore test from backups, to confirm recovery works in case of a problem during this storage change. Could be to a similar test system, which can then be used to practice the procedure.
Absent some out of band console, a safe method could be to use another host. Safe in that they are booted the usual way with remote access via ssh, not booting rescue media or pivot_root tricks.
Shutdown the instance. Move the disk and attach it to a different instance.
Reduce the size of the unmounted file system. On Linux, ext4 and and possibly other file system types can be reduced. xfs cannot, in which case consider a file level backup restore onto a new smaller volume instead.
Reduce the size of the partition, with parted or other tools.
Swing the disk back over to the instance that owns it.

In the future, consider using LVM. Were the storage created as a 100 GB volume group with 20 GB used, volume creation and extension could be done with no downtime at all.

While LVM is a good idea, even with LVM one is not able to reduce filesystem size online and the tedious procedure is required. I saw many systems with LVM... and fully (and wrongly) allocated. The most useful lesson from this, to say in clear, is to never allocate all the available space right away, rather, always allocate a reasonable amount and leave the rest unallocated, even if that's a lot. To extend space is way easier than to reclaim it. For instance, 30 GiB is enough for the root FS; for a cluttered and sloppy managed system it might be 50 GiB, but never more.
